# Explain Pre-Teens and Teens the problems of a surveillance state and internet privacy

Tags: teen, pre-teen

I want to present an audience, consisting of mostly teens and pre-teens, the problems of a surveillance state, e.g. if everything is recorded what you are doing. That leads to an internal scissor in your head, i.e. you forget words and therefore actions if you are not allowed to use them, and it changes your thinking.

My problem is that I have already an approach, but it is still quite complex (I was thinking about something like playing "Taboo" where they should describe actions without saying a list of words, which gets bigger and bigger). But I've been told that this approach is a) too long and b) way too complex.

So I was wondering if there exists another approach which is easier to explain and to understand (target audience is between 11-16, between "We have used this strange thing called PC once" and "well, I am using the PC for mailing & facebook"). Preferably the approach should be included in a game, after the learning and understanding is much better in a game than just telling them the problems

Comment: Can you clarify how this is related to parenting? While we may be able to provide guidance on talking to teens, this is more am education question

Comment: Well, after the audience will be mainly consisting out of my siblings and cousins, and I could not see a big different towards questions like "How can I talk to my child about pornography", which is partly targeting the same direction, I thought that maybe I could get some information and ideas about my problem, too.

Comment: How much time do you have, on the whole? I am not sure if the "internal scissors" bit may not be going over their heads (I know _Adults_ who fail to see the problem...); are you sure that is your aim is that deep-going yet, or would you be content with having them see how surveillance is bad for _them_ for a start?

Comment: Well, my first idea was around three hours, but that is in fact my main problem: I am partly so far away from ground that I can not see the problems, which is why I am looking for easier ways to approach that (or even break it down to simpler messages).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually trying to teach here. I'm not sure complexity is your issue here, but clarity. I'm VTCing because it's unclear, to me, what you're actually asking.

Comment: "The audience will be mainly consisting out of my siblings and cousins" -- this is good news.  It means that you can ask them some informal questions while you're doing your preparation.  Their interests, current knowledge and questions can give you guidance for your preparation.

Comment: A very interesting topic, but as it is stated right now I'd say you are trying to prepare a lecture for future terrorists on how to avoid being detected... ;) Rephrase the question please.

Comment: @Dariusz: Where is that stated? Funny theory...

Comment: The intent seems positive, but it doesn't seem connected to parenting. Can you clarify what it is you are asking - is it about how to teach thought experiments/philosophical constructs?

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Yes, that should be the general direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love teaching through playing games, but in this case, I can't think of anything.

However, young people of this age are quite interested in current events.  So, I would pick a couple of examples taken from news stories.

You could think about how much you want to lecture and how much you want to listen.  It partly depends on the number of young people in your audience; it also depends on how much time you have available and how much material you feel you need to cover.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to go in at the deep end with the internal scissors. Start out simpler: Ask them to think about something they would only tell their very best friend about. Then have them imagine everyone knowing all of a sudden. Because that is, an a way, what is happening: you are mailing or IM'ing your best friend, and some person you don't even know can read it.
That is admittedly not the main point yet, but it is the point at which your audience can be pulled into the topic.
Once they have realised that bit, random strangers reading their private messages to their friends, you can help them move on.
Admittedly, I have no idea how to pack this into a game, but it may be a better starting-point to make them see that there is indeed an issue.

Answer (score -2):

> I want to present an audience, consisting of mostly teens and pre-teens, the problems of a surveillance state, [...]. That leads to an internal scissor in your head, i.e. you forget words and therefore actions if you are not allowed to use them, and it changes your thinking.

When I Google "internal scissor", I don't get any relevant articles. Are you sure this a real scientific theory with a sound basis in fact? If not, maybe you should re-evaluate the content of the lecture. The first step in explaining something to others is to make sure you understand it well yourself. You also have to research it fully to make sure you are using standard terminology.

Just based on ordinary experience, I kind of doubt the "internal scissor" theory as outlined above. In a constant surveillance scenario, I would hardly "forget" words I'm not allowed to use. If anything, I'd be more aware of words I'm not allowed to use than otherwise.

Comment: You will forget words, just look up 1984 (as an example)....

Comment: 1984 is a work of fiction, not a work of science.

Comment: You don't "forget" them, but you don't use them and change your whole thinking based on this.

Comment: This is more of an argument with the premise of the question than answering what was asked. To get clarification from the OP, comments would be better; disputing what he wants to teach is not productive as either answer or comment, though.

Comment: @Erica Well, IMHO if the premise of a question is very off, pointing that out may be the only real answer. The hope is OP will look up better-researched reasons for opposing state surveillance and base his lecture on them, and I'd consider that a "productive" outcome. Though of course such a Q and A has very narrow applicability to other situations.

Comment: http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/q/123/4054 is the canonical meta that discusses "arguing with the premise" -- in a nutshell, clarification or argument as an "answer" is not _good answering behavior_ for Parenting.SE. Consider the tone as well: is "gobbledygook" more likely to encourage calm reexamination and research, or an emotionally defensive reaction?